# How to select from joined MySQL tables?

Tags: sql, mysql

I basically have two tables:

```
A(id int, name varchar(10), info varchar(10))
B(id int, item varchar(10))

A
1 A Hello
2 B World
3 C Foo

B
1 apple
1 orange
1 hammer
2 glass
2 cup
```

Using the following query...

```
mysql> SELECT a.id, a.name, a.info, group_concat(b.item SEPARATOR ' ')
       FROM a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON (a.id=b.id)
       GROUP BY 1,2,3;
```

I get the desired output:

```
+------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id   | name | info  | group_concat(b.item separator ' ') |
+------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | A    | Hello | apple orange hammer                | 
|    2 | B    | World | glass cup                          | 
|    3 | C    | Foo   | NULL                               | 
+------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

I would now like to modify the query to get a result table containing the same information but only those who have items starting with the letter o, `(like 'o%')` How do I get the following output?

```
+------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id   | name | info  | group_concat(b.item separator ' ') |
+------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | A    | Hello | apple orange hammer                |                        
+------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

Note that I still want to present the whole string `'apple orange hammer'`, not only `'orange'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another way to do it:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.info, group_concat(b.item SEPARATOR ' ') AS items
   FROM a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON (a.id=b.id)
   GROUP BY 1,2,3
   HAVING items REGEXP '[[:<:]]o';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  a.id, a.name, a.info, group_concat(b.item SEPARATOR ' ') AS bs
FROM    a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        b
ON      b.id = a.id
GROUP BY
        id, name, info
HAVING   
        bs RLIKE '[[:<:]]o'
```

or this (more index efficient):

```
SELECT  a.id, a.name, a.info,
        (
        SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(b.item SEPARATOR ' ') AS bs
        FROM    b
        WHERE   b.id = a.id
        ) AS bs
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT b.id
        FROM    b
        WHERE   item LIKE 'o%'
        ) q
JOIN    a
ON      a.id = q.id
```

The latter query is faster if you have a composite index on `b (item, id)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.info, group_concat(b.item SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON (a.id=b.id)
WHERE a.id in (select id from b where upper(SUBSTRING(b.item,0,1)) = 'O')
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT a.id, a.name, a.info, group_concat(b.item SEPARATOR ' ')
  FROM a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON (a.id=b.id)
  GROUP BY 1,2,3)
WHERE a.id IN (SELECT bb.id FROM b AS bb WHERE name like 'o%');
```

I doubt this performs well, but it seems logical to me.

Answer (score 0):

After the group by you need to use having to do the like operator on the group_concat.

```
Group By 1,2,3
HAVING group_concat(b.item SEPARATOR ' ') like ('%o%')
```

Please note I am just looking for any o you would need to adjust the like statement to match your requirements.